# Trying to get location with LocationManager.getCurrentLocation always returns null?

Tags: android, kotlin, locationmanager

So I have an app that has multiple fragments. Each time the user navigates to a new fragment, I want to store the device location. All fragments live under a single Activity.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

in my Acitivity:

```
    fun getLocation(context: Context, consumer: Consumer<Location?>): Boolean {
        return if (checkLocationPermission()) {
            mService.getLocation(context, consumer)
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
```

in my LocationService (locationService is bound to my activity)

```
    @RequiresPermission(value = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
    fun getLocation(context: Context, consumer: Consumer<Location?>): Boolean {
        return if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION)
            && manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            manager.getCurrentLocation(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                null,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
                consumer)
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
```

Finally, here's how I request location in my Fragment.
In my fragment:

```
    val a = requireActivity() as MyActivity
    a.getLocation(a) { loc -> 
        // this callback always takes about 30 seconds to execute, and then loc is null
    }
```

I'm testing this on my pixel 3a phone. I'm indoors so I don't know if that affects the GPS, but its able to show my location at least in google maps.

I've also tried testing this on an emulator (Pixel 2 API 30), and that *does* return a location, but its always the default location (Palo Alto Googleplex) even if I change device location in the emulator settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Fused Location Provider to fetch the location!

Comment: Can you elaborate why?